# Два инпута с одинаковым именем

Tags: html, webbrowser, браузер

Всем привет. Есть два инпута с одинаковым именем.

```
<input type="hidden" name="state" value="0">
<input type="checkbox" name="state" value="1">
```

Браузер отправляет их оба, хотя должен ведь перезаписать?

[image]

Я что-то пропустил в этой жизни и теперь это нормальное поведение?

Comment: Глюк браузера, на сервер конечно же одно значение приходит, как и должно быть.